# permanently applying password complexity rules

Tags: password

Password complexity rules in /etc/pam.d/common-password are overwritten during system updates to auth modules

The advice I have seen is to edit **/etc/security/pwquality.conf** to get round this problem

```
minlen = 15
dcredit = -1
ucredit = -1
lcredit = -1
ocredit = -1
```

However, this does not seem to be read as I can still enter short passwords

/etc/pam.d/common-password file typically needs the line

**password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=10**

but any changes in here will get wiped ( I can vouch for this after seeing the change I applied on 90 boxes being overwritten with the default after patching)

I'm aware of the directory 
**/usr/share/pam-configs**
which allows you to apply your own files and there is a **pwquality** file in there already with the following details

```
Name: Pwquality password strength checking
Default: yes
Priority: 1024
Conflicts: cracklib
Password-Type: Primary
Password:
        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
Password-Initial:
        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
```

In short, I'm not sure what else needs changing for password complexity rules to apply so that changes are permanent when patching